# Java GUI will not display all the answers in the for loop

Tags: java, user-interface, for-loop, textarea

So I made a separate program that prints out ALL the prime numbers up to an inputed number (the limit). It works perfectly but when I added the code into my GUI code, it only displays the last prime number. For example, I enter 9 and it only displays 7 since that is the last prime number before 9. Obviously, the GUI code is messing up with the for loop and I have no idea how to fix it. Here is the code (is right at the bottom of my program) that displays the answers in a text area (the other part of the code is just setting up the GUI). Please help!

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){ 

    //turns the inputNum text into type int and parsed into int input

      //iterates through each number
        for(){

            //prints the primes that returned true in the isPrime method ONLY
            if(isPrime(num)){


            }
        }
}
        public static boolean checkForPrime(int num){

            //for loop that checks if the inputed number is prime
```

Comment: Is `answers.setText(answers.getText() + String.valueOf(num));` what you're looking for or more like a countdown that requires the textbox to be refreshed each iteration.

Comment: So I enter 10 in the text field, then 2 3 5 7 should display in the text area as the answer.

Comment: `setText` is doing exactly what it advertises as doing, changes the text of the field from what it is to what you give it.

Comment: Then my comment basically has the code to do so although it'd be advisable to *Build* the *String* then set the text. The iterations towards the answer won't be visible anyway so why not wait to you have the full text?

Answer (score 1):

Don't call `setText(...)` on your JTextArea since that **replaces** the current text in the JTextArea with the new text. Instead call `append(myText + "\n");` on your JTextArea so that new lines will be created, each with a copy of the new answer.

e.g,

```
if(checkForPrime(num)){
    // assuming that answers is a JTextArea
    answers.append(String.valueOf(num) + "\n");
}
```

The append method will add the String passed into it to the text that is already displayed in the 
JTextArea.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the text each loop.  Do this:

```
if(checkForPrime(num)){
  answers.setText(answers.getText(num + " "));//The space separates the numbers and makes it a String
}
```

This will add to the numbers each time it loops.